# Encoding and Decoding Strings using UnsafeMutablePointer in Swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsstring, nsstringencoding, iobluetooth

I'm having trouble converting strings to and from UnsafeMutablePointers. The following code doesn't work, returning the wrong string.

```
// func rfcommChannelData(rfcommChannel: IOBluetoothRFCOMMChannel!, data dataPointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>, length dataLength: Int)
func receivingData(data dataPointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>, length dataLength: Int) {
    let data = NSData(bytes: dataPointer, length: dataLength)
    println("str = \(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding))")
}

// - (IOReturn)writeSync:(void *)data length:(UInt16)length;
func sendingData(data: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>, length: UInt16) {
    receivingData(data: data, length: Int(length))
}


var str: NSString = "Hello, playground"
var data = str.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!
var bytes = data.bytes

sendingData(&bytes, UInt16(data.length))
```

A link to the playground file is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xtzzjsc1jee1my7/DecodingStrings.playground.zip?dl=0). If anyone has experience using UnsafeMutablePointers in Swift for strings, I would very much appreciate some guidance as I have made no progress in the last few days. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With

```
var bytes = data.bytes
sendingData(&bytes, UInt16(data.length))
```

you pass the address of the variable `bytes` itself to the function, so what you see is the bytes that are used to represent that pointer.

What you probably want is

```
let str = "Hello, playground"
let data = str.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!
sendingData(UnsafeMutablePointer(data.bytes), UInt16(data.length))
```

to pass the pointer to the data bytes.

You should also consider
to use `NSUTF8StringEncoding` instead, because a conversion to 
`NSASCIIStringEncoding` can fail.